# C# - Adding Constraints on Derived Classes

Tags: c#

I have a C# class that looks something like this:

```
public abstract class Department<T> where T : ShoppingItem
{
  protected string Name { get; set; }

  protected string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I then want to derive two classes from `Department`. Each of these classes also must work with `ShoppingItem` elements. At this time, I have:

```
public class ClothingDepartment<T> : Department<T> where T : ShoppingItem
{
  ...
}
```

When I attempt to initialize a `ClothingDepartment`, I get an error. I'm trying to initialize it like this:

```
var department = new ClothingDepartment();
```

The error I get is `Using the generic type ClothingDepartment<T> requires 1 type arguments`. I don't understand that.

I also want to use a constraint along-side an interface. However, I'm not having luck with that either.

Comment: you haven't passed anything for `T`

Comment: I'm curious about using generic type. What is use of `T`? Maybe exploring documentation of `IList<T>` and `List<T>` would help you understand declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Shopping item to create the other classes you can then initialise the Clothing department like so:

```
var clothingDepartment = new ClothingDepartment<Shirt>();

public class Shirt : ShoppingItem
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, you need to pass a type parameter when you are instantiating the class. Because of the constraint on the type parameter, you will need to pass a ShoppingItem class, or a class that that inherits from ShoppingItem. The compiler will build a ClothingDepartment class where all "T" references are replaced with the ShoppingItem class you passed.

Pass in a type parameter when new'ing up the class like this:

```
var department = new ClothingDepartment<ShoppingItem>();
```

Answer (score 0):

you class is generic class which needs derived ShoppingItem class.

```
var department = new ClothingDepartment<DerivedShoppingItem>();
```

---

```
public class DerivedShoppingItem : ShoppingItem
{
     DerivedShoppingItem() : base()
     {
     }

     ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second class should be as below if you want to use `new ClothingDepartment();`

```
public class ClothingDepartment : Department<ShoppingItem>
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to passing a Type into the type parameter in `ClothingDepartment<T>`, you could specify the type parameter of `Department<T>` directly in the `ClothingDepartment` class definition. For example, if `ClothingDepartment` should always use a `Shirt` as the `ShoppingItem`, then you could do:

```
public class ClothingDepartment : Department<Shirt>
{
  ...
}
```

This would allow you to instantiate `ClothingDepartment` as you were trying to, without a type parameter:

```
var department = new ClothingDepartment();
```